# Python 3.5: Function not yielding the proper results

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code isn't yielding the correct output that I want it to do. Here is my code:

```
def rows(numbers):
        count = 0
        for i in numbers:
            if count == 3:
                print(i, end = " ")
                count = 0
            else:
                print(i, end = " ")
                count += 1
```

Next, I will show you the output in my program, followed by the correct output (Note that the numbers are randomized):

```
91 77 14 36 1 88 13 88 19 40 90
```

The correct output shows this:

```
91 77 14 36 
1 88 13 88
19 40 90
```

Comment: If count is 3, you _want_ to add a newline. `if count == 3: print(i)`

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you'd like an alternative way of tackling the problem, you might see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is simple. When `count` equals `3`, you *want* to add a newline after printing out the last digit, otherwise the next set of 4 numbers will be printed on the same line. So, in summary, this is what you do:

```
if count == 3:
    print(i)
    count = 0
```

---

One handy trick to solving this problem another way is to chunk your input into small lists and print each one separately.

```
for i in range(0, len(numbers), 4):
     print(*numbers[i:i + 4])

91 77 14 36
1 88 13 88
19 40 90
```

Use python's list slicing notation to get slices of 4 numbers at a time `[i : i + 4]` and then call `print` with the `*` argument to unpack them.

Comment: wow, didn't know about the `*` trick, thats actually very useful...